How to reliably determine the name of an application for use in Gnome: Favorite Applications?
I have ran the following command to setup my Favorite Applications menu:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "[ \
    'docker-desktop.desktop', \
    'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', \
    'firefox-esr.desktop', \
    'github-desktop.desktop', \
    'gnome-system-monitor.desktop', \
    'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', \
    'gnome-tweaks.desktop' \
]"

This is working perfectly (after working out the precise application names).
However I can't work out what the application name is for gnome-control-center - I have tried all of these:
    'gnome-control-center', \
    'gnome-control-center.desktop', \
    'gnome-controlcenter.desktop', \
    'gnome.control-center.desktop', \
    'org.gnome-control-center.desktop', \
    'org.gnome.control-center.desktop', \
    'org.gnome.controlcenter.desktop', \
    '/usr/bin/gnome-control-center', \
    '/usr/bin/gnome-control-center.desktop', \

None of them work. "Settings" (A.K.A. Control Center) does not show in my list of Favorite Applications.
How can I add it to my menu please? Do I have the application name wrong?
I am able to successfully launch it from the Terminal using both gnome-control-center and /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
I am also looking for the name of the Text Editor (gnome-text-editor) application - as I can't work that one out either, to add it to my Favorites.
How can we reliably determine the name of each application please?
I am running Gnome on Debian 12.
Note: I actually ended up setting the favorites system-wide for all users via 00-favorite-apps - but the same is observed either way).


Pure guess since I don't use gnome. What about launching that application then watching what ps -efl tells ?

@MC68020 I should have mentioned, but I tried ps. If I do ps -efl | grep control then it gives gnome-control-center

Can you find a file named gnome-control-center.desktop in your home directory or any subdir of it ? In not just create one from scratch and refer to  gnome-control-center.desktop in your gsettings.

Look for a matching .desktop file in /usr/share/applications. You can check the file list of the corresponding package. For gnome-control-center on Debian Bookworm, I see a org.gnome.Settings.desktop file. For the same package on Ubuntu 22.04, it was gnome-control-center.desktop.
For gnome-text-editor on Debian Bookworm, there's a org.gnome.TextEditor.desktop file.
